# Does Racket Scheme provide a Smalltalk-like image-based environment?

Tags: scheme, racket, smalltalk

Could anyone with experience with Racket Scheme tell me whether it provides a Smalltalk-like, image-based environment?  By "image-based", I mean that one typically begins with a snapshot of the programming environment, does stuff to it (adding functions, objects, and GUI elements), and then saves everything to a new snapshot at the end.  I'm also looking for things like an interface builder that is integrated into the environment, object inspectors, etc.  Does Racket offer this kind of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Racket is not image-based, no. It does have a [GUI designer](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=mred-designer.plt&owner=orseau), though.

Comment: If Racket had something like SBCL's `save-lisp-and-die`, that would be a "yes" answer (even if that was not normal Racket usage).